# Javascript escape Asp.net encoding

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an html textbox and am entering double quotes in the text box.

E.g

```
I "a a person
```

I am using the Javsacript escape function and it encodes the quote to `%22` which is correct

To the last point before hitting the server I have `%22` but when I get it at the server by Request as follows:

```
Request["myJson"].Trim();
```

The `%22` is converted back to "

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You'd better not use `escape`, cause it is deprecated. Use similar function `encodeURIComponent`.
- I don't know, what for do you need escaped string on the server, but if you really need it, just apply this function twice.

Comment: It is being encoded properly but the problem is that when I get it on the server the value changes back to " rather than %21...is there anything else I can do

Comment: This is how parsing of GET/POST params is working for all servers. **Apply this function twice**: `encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(data))`

Comment: Auto-decoding at servers happens cause of `Content-encoding: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header of your request. You may change this behaviour by altering header as well.

Comment: Can you tell me how to change it back to I am " person on the server side using asp.net???

Comment: I suppose, with `HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode`, but I'm not familiar with asp at all. In case of emergency google for `asp UrlDecode` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of the character escaping on the server-side if you want using `HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(Request["myJson"].Trim());`

Comment: but my Json is not a field ...it has many name value pairs...and I dont want to encode everything that is why I am sending it encoded from the client side.